# SELECT DISTINCT result encapsulated in a VIEW.

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, view

The issue I have is I have a table with multiple rows for each day a product is being shipped.

If the product is going out on Monday, Tuesday, and Thursday there will be 3 row entries resulting in

```
ID  rtedat
1     M
2     T
3     H
```

I am trying to return a single string per product.

This is the original code from the VIEW I am using

```
SELECT     TOP (1) rtedow
FROM          dbo.CUSTROUTE AS i
WHERE      (cusnum = dbo.CUSTOMER.cusnum) AND (co_num = dbo.CUST_CO.co_num) AND (rternk = '1')
ORDER BY credat, cusrtetky) AS main_rte_days
```

Problem is the top(1). The logic in the view wasn't geared towards multiple days.

I need to change this to result in a single string that would look like M,T,H

This code I tried was working but the problem I had was once I tried to insert it into the view it returned that the '=' after the first select was invalid. Not sure what was going on there.

```
DECLARE @combinedString VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @combinedString = COALESCE(@combinedString + ', ', '') + rtedow
FROM dbo.CUSTROUTE
WHERE (cusnum = dbo.CUSTOMER.cusnum) AND (co_num = dbo.CUST_CO.co_num) AND (rternk = '1')
SELECT @combinedString as rtedow
```

Then I was trying another way someone suggested using XML

```
SELECT DISTINCT rtedow
FROM dbo.CUSTROUTE v1
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT rtedow + ',' 
              FROM dbo.CUSTROUTE v2
              WHERE (v2.cusnum = dbo.Customer.cusnum) = (v1.cusnum = dbo.Customer.cusnum)
                  AND (v2.co_num = dbo.CUST_CO.co_num) = (v1.co_num = dbo.CUST_CO.co_num) 
                  AND (rternk = '1')
              ORDER BY ID 
                  FOR XML PATH('') )  D ( rtedow )
WHERE (cusnum = dbo.CUSTOMER.cusnum) AND (co_num = dbo.CUST_CO.co_num) AND (rternk = '1')
```

but I believe the problem there is the inside WHERE (v2.cusnum = dbo.Customer.cusnum) = etc...

I am at a lose here.

Answer (score 0):

I am a ms SQL person and to achieve this I would use a function that did this processing and then get that function to return the string back to the view.

I would usually declare a temp table as a variable and then load this with the required records and then use a while loop to load the data into the string returning this as the final value.

If you can give me the table structure I can probably knock up some sample code for you.